biblatex-publist: marginyear not displaying when no author is given
I'm using the biblatex package with the publist style to format my bibliography in LaTeX. I've noticed that when a bibliography entry doesn't have an author field, the marginyear doesn't appear in the output.
Here are two examples from my .bib file:
% Entry with author, marginyear appears
@online{entry1,
    title        = {An Interesting Article},
    author       = {John Doe},
    date         = {2023-11-28},
    url          = {https://example.com/article1},
    keywords     = {press}
}

% Entry without author, marginyear does not appear
@online{entry2,
    title        = {Another Interesting Article},
    date         = {2023-05-23},
    url          = {https://example.com/article2},
    keywords     = {press}
}

And here's a minimal working example of my LaTeX document:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[%
    bibstyle=publist,
    backend=biber,
    natbib=true,
    sorting=ydnt,
    uniquelist=false,
    uniquename=false,
    dashed=false,
    maxbibnames=99,
    plnumbering=none,
    plauthorhandling=highlight,
    hlyear=false,
    marginyear=true,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword=press]

\end{document}

I would like the marginyear to display for all entries, even if the author field is missing.

It may be a bug of biblatex-publist. You can file a bug report at https://github.com/jspitz/biblatex-publist/issues.

That's by design, marginyear is output with either author or editor. I fail to see the usecase. Do you really want to list an entry in your publication list where you are not either one of the authors or editors?

I am using this setup to format a CV that contains press clippings. These entries sometimes do not have an author. However, the marginyear is still very useful for maintaining a consistent structure because it visually aligns the entries by date.
Is there a way to change the behavior so that the marginyear is displayed even if the author field is missing, or would you suggest a workaround for this use case?

There's not really a quick solution, no. You might try adding a dummy author which expands to an empty string.
